# Where is the TFS database?

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

I've been using TFS 2010 with no problems. I tried adding a user and I got the following error message.
"TF30063: You are not authorized to access <serverName>\DefaultCollection. -The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

I remoted into the server, <serverName>, and opened the TFS Console. The logs mentioned a connection string:

> ConnectionString: Data Source=<serverName>\SS2008;Initial
>   Catalog=Tfs_DefaultCollection;Integrated Security=True

While remoted in I open SQL Server 2008 Management Studio opening the (local) server with Windows Authentication. It shows the connection to be (local)(SQL Server 9.04.03 - <serverName>\Admin), and there is no Tfs_DefaultCollection database.

Can someone tell me what is going on? Was I wrong in connecting to this instance of the database (i.e. Is the log file the wrong place to find the connection string)? Is the database so corrupted that SQL Manager Studio cannot see it anymore, although TFS could? Should I be logging into Management Studio as user SS2008? btw I don't know of any such credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're connecting to the default SQL instance on the database server, when the connection string specifies that the TFS database is in the named instance called SS2008.

When you connect via Management Studion, specify (local)\SS2008 as the server name.

Comment: By the way, I doubt you'll find the solution to your problem by digging around in the database. It looks to me like an access rights issue with the user account that you're connecting to TFS with.

Comment: But I could add users before. My investigations seem to indicate that the database may be corrupted. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/8c936873-9c10-44e6-bab3-e0519fae0dca/ btw I confirmed that the instance serverName/2008 does exist. Thanks.